# what is descartes argument for machines?

Tags: ethics, descartes

what is Descartes argument for why even sophisticated machines will never have capacity to reason? and is the argument agreeable?

Comment: An these issues you can see [Dennis Des Chene](http://www.artsci.wustl.edu/~ddeschen/)'s books and papers.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, can you narrow down the reference?